# How to Lazy Load Canvas Elements

Tags: javascript, canvas, lazy-loading

Let's say I have 100 canvas elements each with content that is operated on by javascript.  This causes the page to hang until all 100 elements are loaded up.  How would you go about lazy loading canvas elements?

Comment: Difficult to comment without more info...What are the elements and how important are each of the different elements to your app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add one canvas at a time using interval. This way a browser could have time to make paint between canvas adds and you wont freeze the browser. Simple example:

```
var index = 0,
    interval;

var drawCanvas = function () {
    // draw canvas here
};

interval = window.setInterval(function () {

    if (index < 100) {
        drawCanvas();
        index += 1;
    } else {
        window.clearInterval(interval);
    }

}, 25);
```